# CXF webservice client, how to handle response from a called webservice?

Tags: java, soap, cxf, webservice-client

i have implemented a webservice client that is used inside a webapplication (using Spring) and this client gets a response in which CXF bailsout and gives me an error message.

The error message is:

> **Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction**

I have found the problem but do not know what i can do to adjust my webservice response handling.

The xml response below works without any problems.

**Works and is accepted ok!**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bar="http://www.dummyurl.com/service-v1.0/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <bar:StartSessionResponse>
            <result>1</result>
        </bar:StartSessionResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The service actually returns:

**Fails and gives me an error!**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <StartSessionResponse xmlns="www.dummyurl.com/service-v1.0/">
            <result xmlns="">1</result>
        </StartSessionResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The difference as far as i can see is in the placing of the

***xmlns="www.dummyurl.com/service-v1.0/*** element, in the success xml it is in the enveloppe, in the failed xml it is on the reponse method.

Is there a way that i can convince CXF to accept the response? Or is the service giving back an abnormal result?

Answer (score 0):

The service is giving back a wrong response in the second case, assuming that the first response is proper.

In the first case "www.dummyurl.com/service-v1.0/" is the namespace of your elements - StartSessionResponse, result is not qualified with the namespace.  In the second case, the StartSessionResponse has the same namespace as the first sample, but the result has a different namespace altogether, taking out xmlns="" for result will make the xml consistent.